# Is there a way to pass an array of type parameters to a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

Working over OpenXml, I've came across this article: [How to: Merge two adjacent cells in a spreadsheet document (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc880096.aspx).

There is a code sample there, that I wanted to refactor. Here is its part:

```
// Insert a MergeCells object into the specified position.
if (worksheet.Elements<CustomSheetView>().Count() > 0)
{
     worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, 
                           worksheet.Elements<CustomSheetView>().First());
}
else if (worksheet.Elements<DataConsolidate>().Count() > 0)
{
     worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, 
                           worksheet.Elements<DataConsolidate>().First());
}
else if (worksheet.Elements<SortState>().Count() > 0)
{
     worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, 
                           worksheet.Elements<SortState>().First());
}
//...and 5 more
```

The best thing I managed is an extension method:

```
public static bool InsertElementAfter<T>(this Worksheet worksheet, 
                                              OpenXmlElement element)
    where T : OpenXmlElement
{
    if (!worksheet.Elements<T>().Any())
        return false;
    else
    {
        worksheet.InsertAfter(element, worksheet.Elements<T>().First());
        return true;
    }
}
```

But its usage looks as much terrible as the original code:

```
if (!worksheet.InsertElementAfter<CustomSheetView>(mergeCells))
    if (!worksheet.InsertElementAfter<DataConsolidate>(mergeCells))
        if (!worksheet.InsertElementAfter<SortState>(mergeCells))
            //...and 5 more
```

If I could somehow declare an array (or something) of type parameters, I would be able to write something like this:

```
foreach (var T in typeParameterList)
{
    if (worksheet.InsertElementAfter<T>(mergeCells))
        break;
}
```

But I do not know any way to do this.

So what are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a fluent API for this. The result could allow code like this:

```
worksheet.InsertAfter<CustomSheetView>(mergeCells)
         .Or<DataConsolidate>()
         .Or<SortState>();
```

There are two advantages to this fluent API:

1. It is very expressive
2. It works without reflection.

The implementation of the API would require a class that holds the values and the `Or()` method:

```
public class ChainedElementInserter
{
    OpenXmlElement _element;
    Worksheet _worksheet;
    bool _previousResult;

    // ctor that initializes all three fields goes here.

    public ChainedElementInserter Or<T>()
        where T : OpenXmlElement
    {
        if (!_previousResult)
            _previousResult = _worksheet.InsertElementAfter<T>(_element);

        return this;
    }
}
```

The `InsertAfter` extension method starts this chain and looks like so:

```
public static ChainedElementInserter InsertAfter<T>(this Worksheet worksheet, 
                                  OpenXmlElement element)
    where T : OpenXmlElement
{
    return new ChainedElementInserter(
        worksheet, element, worksheet.InsertElementAfter<T>(element));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You gave me a great push forward, as I had never thought of doing such kind of trick. Your answer does give an opportunity to avoid using reflection and shorten the code without any redundancy!

Comment: I let myself edit your answer to show the way I used your code. Hope you agree with these edits. Thank you again.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov: Nice. Now it's even shorter.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is what they call in C++ a "typelist". However, these are unfortunately not supported in C#.

What you can do is simulate this behavior by creating a bunch of classes with various type arguments and making them 'recursive' as follows:

```
public interface ITypelist { Type[] List { get; } }
public class Typelist<T1> : ITypelist {
    public Type[] List { get { return new Type[]{typeof(T1)}; }}
}
public class Typelist<T1, T2> : ITypelist {
    public Type[] List { get { return new Type[]{typeof(T1), typeof(T2)}; }}

}
// etc
```

Then you can use that to pass lists of types:

```
worksheet.InsertElementAfter<Typelist<T1, T2, T3>>(mergeCells)
```

You can implement the typelist to add more trickery. For example, you can split 'head' (typeof(T1)) from 'tail' (the rest as a Typelist) and make the typelist only handle the first type. Using tricks like that you can iterate the list and add behavior for multiple types.

Note that the interface is added so that you can add a restriction, e.g.:

```
void InsertElementAfter<T>(...) where T:ITypelist
```

...Unfortunately you cannot pass methods and types as 'generic' to a method (yet?), so best you can do is to pass them as string and use reflection to make it a 'real' method (using MakeGenericType / ...).

Eventually you will end up with a big helper class that looks something like this:

```
// ...

public class Typelist<T1, T2> : ITypelist
{
    public Type MakeGenericType(Type t)
    {
        return t.MakeGenericType(typeof(T1));
    }

    public MethodInfo MakeGenericMethod(MethodInfo method)
    {
        return method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T1));
    }

    public Type Head { get { return typeof(T1); } }
    public Typelist<T2> Tail { get { return new Typelist<T2>(); } }

    public Type[] List { get { return new Type[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2) }; } }
}

// ...

public static class Ext
{
    public static void InvokeAll<T1>(this Typelist<T1> typelist, MethodInfo baseMethod, object obj, object[] pars)
    {
        typelist.MakeGenericMethod(baseMethod).Invoke(obj, pars);
        // tail so no recursion
    }

    public static void InvokeAll<T1, T2>(this Typelist<T1, T2> typelist, MethodInfo baseMethod, object obj, object[] pars)
    {
        typelist.MakeGenericMethod(baseMethod).Invoke(obj, pars);
        InvokeAll(typelist.Tail, baseMethod, obj, pars);
    }
}
```

Question is if this is a good idea or not... The added value is that you can exploit the type system and obtain the ability to pass lists of types by using generics, the downside is that you have a lot of code and still have to use reflection.

Comment: It looks too complicated for this kind of task. However thank you for the effort

Comment: I would upvote it, if it would be more than just reflection cleverly disguised.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yea, that was my own conclusion as well :-) Well, the question was to pass multiple types and that's exactly what I do. I was actually thinking about using dynamic, which is also sort-of reflection... eventually it just doesn't get much better. Typelists simply aren't supported in C#. Only debatable that remains is if disguising reflection after generics has value... My point was to explain how you can pass lists of types, what would happen if you do and what is required in a language for this to work properly - In C++ this is more than reflection, here unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: A pity it's not possible. It would be handy.

Answer (score 2):

Reflections can help you invoke the method at runtime with correct type.

```
Type[] typeParamList = new Type[] { typeof(CustomSheetView), typeof(DataConsolidate) } //And 9 more

MethodInfo method = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod("InsertElementAfter");
foreach (var type in typeParamList)
{
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type });
    genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { worksheet, mergeCells });
}
```

Comment: If you did not understand, I do not have `typeParameterList`; it's a pseudo-collection thet I am asking about

Comment: I dont want to be rude but you will have to think a bit for yourself aswel. My code was psuedo aslo, you cant just copy paste it. But ill try to rewrite it so you can just paste it in there. Give me a min

Comment: Ehm.. So reading it over and over again.. No I really dont understand what you are after. Why dont you just declare that type param list you are talking about. The 8 types seems to be known already ?  new Type[] { typeof(CustomSheetView) }

Comment: @Evelie: There is one real bug in your method. v.GetType() will always be `Type` if `typeParameterList` is a `Type[]`. Furthermore, passing `v` to the method doesn't make much sense either. You should be passing the parameters of the method `InsertElementAfter`.

Comment: Ah yes when I wrote it initally I thought to iterate the objects and get the types from them. Instead by iterating the types one woudlnt need to use the "GetType". If all types are knows in the typeParametersList i think you can use MakeGenericMethod(typeParameterList) and just use it for all types. Right? But ofcourse you are correct.

Comment: Edited. I think it does make more sense now. But yes, your solution is way more elegant. Upvoted

Comment: The previous edit was more correct. The OP doesn't have instances of the classes he wants to use as generic arguments.

Comment: But to "insert at MergeCells object into the specified position" he must have an instance of MergeCells ?

Comment: Yes, but the type of mergeCells is not the generic argument. Please check the question again.

Comment: Anyway reedited it for the 10th time.. Now it should show how he can use the paramlist he wants to invoke all the generics. Thanks for your help Daniel. Really appreciate it

Comment: Looks quite good. There is one problem left: `InsertElementAfter` is an extension method. It is not declared on `Worksheet`.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately he doesnt provide the class where the extension resides in. Ill assume its called "Extensions" :)

Comment: @Evelie: The point is: You can't call extension methods like instance methods. You need to call it as what they are - static methods: `genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { worksheet, mergeCells });`

Comment: hehe my Original code had null there. Forgot to change it back when I edited.. Im amazed how nothing gets by you without you noticing :D

Comment: @Evelie Now your answer does make sense. Thanks for all your effort (+1), however I prefer to avoid reflection when possible, so Daniel did showed a great way to do that

Comment: @Evelie: Yeah, nothing gets by me, harharhar ;) BTW: You are still missing the first parameter of the call to the extension method: `worksheet`. Please refer to my previous comment.

Comment: Yes thanks for all help. I think we all can agree on Daniels solution being the better one. But still want to provide a functionable answer :) Thanks for your time